# How to convert an object with keys representing a number list ("1.1.1") into a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, console.log

Let's consider I have the following *plain* object:

```
var numberedList = {
    "1": "Text of 1",
    "1.1": ["array of 1.1"],
    "1.2": {
        key: "object of 1.2"
    },
    "1.1.1": 999,
    "1.2.1": true,
    "1.2.2": function () {
        return "function of 1.2.2";
    },
    "1.3": null,
    "2": 2
}
```

I want to accomplish the following multidimensional array:

*To easy explain myself:*

```
[
    ["1",
        [
            [
                [
                    "1.1",
                    [
                        "1.1.1"
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    "1.2",
                    [
                        "1.2.1",
                        "1.2.2"
                    ]
                ],
            ],
            "1.3"
        ]
    ],
    "2"
]
```

Final array:

```
[
    [
        "Text of 1",
        [
            [
                [
                    ["array of 1.1"],
                    [
                        999
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    {
                        key: "object of 1.2"
                    },
                    [
                        true,
                        function()
                        {
                            return "function of 1.2.2";
                        }
                    ]
                ],
            ],
            null
        ]
    ],
    2
]
```

Note that the deepest elements are not wrapped into an array.

How can I do a **generic recursion function** to accomplish this in pure **vanilla js?**

The main objective is to perform a tree of `console.group()` calls such as the `console.groupEnd()`would be also called on the end of each tree branch. It would be a bonus to help me to accomplish this also – given the object on the top execute these console calls.

Comment: what you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: I'm really struggling with recursiveness using split() and then slice().join(.) so I get, for example given the item 1.1.1 the array [1, 1.1] and so on

Comment: pls share your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tm63rwsf/

Comment: add your code in your question, So other will stop downvote your question...

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution,

```js
var numberedList = { "1": "Text of 1", "1.1": ["array of 1.1"], "1.2": { key: "object of 1.2" }, "1.1.1": 999, "1.2.1": true, "1.2.2": function () { return "function of 1.2.2"; }, "1.3": null, "2": 2 }


function gen(numberedList) {
    let result = Object.keys(numberedList).reduce((res, key) => {
        let indexs = key.split(".");
        let lastindex = indexs.pop()
        indexs.reduce((res, i) => res[i], res)[lastindex] = [key]
        return res
    }, []);

    result.shift(); // Removing first item, Becouse index count from 0;
    return result
}

console.log(gen(numberedList))
```

You need to create a `trimer` function, to trim this result, for removing brackets ([])

Comment: To generate a tree for object values, replace `Object.keys` -> `Object.entries`,  AND `(res, key)`  -> `(res, [key,value])`, AND `[lastindex]  = [key]` -> `[lastindex] = [value]`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in the future, please include your attempted code, or at least one relevant version of it, in the question.  It's not a problem to refer to JSFiddle or the like for additional context, but the question should be complete enough without it.

---

Here I use a generic helpers, `setPath`, which takes a path such as `['foo', 0, 'bar', 'baz']`, a new result, say, 'new result', and creates an updated copy of a nested object/array with the value at that path set to the new value:

```js
setPath 
  (['foo', 1, 'bar', 'baz'])
  ("new result")
  ({foo: [{bar: {qux: 3}}, {bar: {qux: 5}}], corge: 8})

//=> {foo: [{bar: {qux: 3}}, {bar: {qux: 5, baz: "new result"}}], corge: 8}
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(Here integers represent array indices and strings represent object keys.)

Then it's a simple matter of converting your input structure into an array of path-value objects, and `reduce`-ing that by calling `setPath` with each of them on a target array.

```js
const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const nest = (o) =>
  Object .entries (o) .map (
    ([k, v]) => [k .split ('.') .map (Number), v]
  ) .reduce ((a, [p, v]) => setPath (p) ([[v]]) (a), []) .slice (1)

const numberedList = {"1": "Text of 1", "1.1": ["array of 1.1"], "1.2": {key: "object of 1.2"}, "1.1.1": 999, "1.2.1": true, "1.2.2": function () {return "function of 1.2.2";}, "1.3": null, "2": 2}

console .log (nest (numberedList))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This isn't precisely the output you requested.  But I don't make much sense out of that output.  You might have to tweak a bit to get it exactly how you want.